# Any frequency checker to determine the c3 to c4 (octave)?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, bass-voice

I am practicing singing and trying to achieve the notes .I am using garage band , trying to hit the c3 note(vocal training). Is there any way to check the frequency of my "vocal pitch" in garage band.

Comment: How about using a tuner app for your phone? Or does it have to be in GarageBand?

Comment: Theres are a couple apps (Vocalist Lite) that can figure out the pitch through your smartphone or mac, read this https://www.reddit.com/r/singing/comments/2dboa6/app_that_tells_you_the_note_youre_singing/?st=iva1zvzk&sh=2d7b7414

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a tuner. They will tell you how close to the pitch you are.

Google tells me that [GarageBand has a tuner](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25011?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). I do not have a Mac, so I can't verify this.

You could also consider a tuner on your phone. My iPhone-wielding friends have generally recommended [ClearTune](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/cleartune-chromatic-tuner/id286799607%3Fmt%3D8&ved=0ahUKEwiV5t7tjJrQAhUBm5QKHa5ICn0QFggdMAE&usg=AFQjCNFCvAps2oXp6y5YUgwi5rfed10SiQ&sig2=X_nOfCOxv8Xl75qsWKLqNA) (also [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.cohortor.gstrings)). I tend to use [gStrings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.cohortor.gstrings). Be careful when googling that.

Finally, you could always use a good old hardware tuner. Available from your friendly local music store (or the interwebs) for a few tens of dollars.

Comment: Good old hardware tuner will be most accurate as the harware is optimized for this purpose, while any app will be limited by the accuracy in the phone/device microphone where the harware is general use.

Comment: @awe I feel that the microphone on my phone is going to be no worse than the one in a $20-30 piece of hardware, surely? And the signal processing chain should have comparable accuracy, if the app developers know what they are doing. I'm aware that might be a big assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem a while back.

You can install an app if you are using a mac or iphone that can return your pitch. They are surprisingly accurate for what they are.

Here's a [blog about the subject](https://www.reddit.com/r/singing/comments/2dboa6/app_that_tells_you_the_note_youre_singing/?st=iva1zvzk&sh=2d7b7414).